# ebpf: BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem calling convention

Tags: bpf, ebpf

Looking at kernel's `sample/bpf/sock_example.c`:

```
struct bpf_insn prog[] = {
                BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_6, BPF_REG_1),
                BPF_LD_ABS(BPF_B, ETH_HLEN + offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol) /* R0 = ip->proto */),
                BPF_STX_MEM(BPF_W, BPF_REG_10, BPF_REG_0, -4), /* *(u32 *)(fp - 4) = r0 */
                BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_2, BPF_REG_10),
                BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_2, -4), /* r2 = fp - 4 */
                BPF_LD_MAP_FD(BPF_REG_1, map_fd),
                BPF_RAW_INSN(BPF_JMP | BPF_CALL, 0, 0, 0, BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem),
                BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JEQ, BPF_REG_0, 0, 2),
                BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_1, 1), /* r1 = 1 */
                BPF_ATOMIC_OP(BPF_DW, BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_0, BPF_REG_1, 0),
                BPF_MOV64_IMM(BPF_REG_0, 0), /* r0 = 0 */
                BPF_EXIT_INSN(),
        };
```

I understand that `eBPF` sets registers r1-r5 to hold arguments to BPF helpers. What I don't understand is why to pass a map `fd` to `BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem`? According to [helpers code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/bpf/helpers.c#L676) :

```
const struct bpf_func_proto bpf_map_lookup_elem_proto = {
    .func       = bpf_map_lookup_elem,
    .gpl_only   = false,
    .pkt_access = true,
    .ret_type   = RET_PTR_TO_MAP_VALUE_OR_NULL,
    .arg1_type  = ARG_CONST_MAP_PTR,
    .arg2_type  = ARG_PTR_TO_MAP_KEY,
};
```

which means both arguments are pointers, and none is the map fd. Unless, I'm looking in the wrong code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File descriptors when writing your program in user space, but later replaced by pointers to the map by the verifier.

#### File Descriptors When Writing Your eBPF Program

You write your eBPF program in user space, where you don't have any address pointer to the map. So you use a file descriptor for referencing that map for the various operations (lookups, updates, deletes) that your program may run.

If writing your program in C, instead of assembly instructions like you do, this is usually abstracted: The program references the map with a C pointer, but the loader (typically relying on libbpf) performs some relocation step to extract metadata about the map from a dedicated ELF section of the object file, retrieves the file descriptor to the map, and inserts it in the relevant bytecode instructions.

#### Kernel Verifier Switches to Pointers

But you are correct: in the kernel, the `BPF_FUNC_map_lookup_elem()` helper and the like use pointers to the maps, not file descriptors. This is at load time, during verification of the program, that the verifier replaces the file descriptors by the pointers to the memory area associated to the maps (see `resolve_pseudo_ldimm64()` from kernel/bpf/verifier.c). It is possible to get a pointer at this time: The verifier *does* have access to the kernel-memory pointers for those maps.

Note that the verifier actually goes even further and, for some map types (hash, arrays), it even replaces the calls to the helpers for map lookups completely, using instead instructions to directly read from the relevant addresses in the map (search for `map_gen_lookup` for details).

Comment: thanks for comprehensive answer! So, if I got it right -- a control application has to create a map (e.g. by means of `libbpf` map API) _before_ invoking eBPF loader (which will retrieve an `fd` to the map and inject that fd in the bytecode instructions). But how will the `fd` end up in a special ELF section?

Comment: FD doesn't end up in the ELF file. Map metadata does. When you try to load your program, libbpf looks at your ELF file and parses this metadata. Depending on whether you ask to reuse an existing map, it looks for a corresponding map with the correct parameters (type, entry sizes etc.) and retrieves a FD (e.g. by opening the pinned path, or with `bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, ...)`. If the program should use a new map, it creates it with `bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, ...)` which returns the FD. In both cases, the FD is then inserted into the bytecode.

Comment: I wonder, what happens if we create a map in the user space application with `bpf_create_map()` (`libbpf` API), which under the hood calls `bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, ...)`? In such case, do we still need to define a map section in a bpf program?

Comment: I think so, otherwise your libbpf-based loader won't know what kind of map it should be using. See `bpf_object__reuse_map()` and `map_is_reuse_compat()` from the lib.

Comment: I guess, `sample/bpf/sock_example.c` and the like, is a special example, which does not exercise BPF loader/relocation/etc. and supplies the program directly as array of BPF instructions. So it is a low-level, which requires to understand internals much more better in full details :-)

Comment: Right, this sample does not compile into an ELF file and produces the bytecode directly. There's not relocation needed, because it directly inserts the file descriptor returned when creating the map. Take any eBPF program written in C, loaded with libbpf, and using maps, and the relocations steps would be necessary to prepare the bytecode :).